# form submit handler is not called

Tags: forms

I tried to mimic the multiple user deletion feature of user.module but for some reason the confirm form submit handler never get called. I don't know where the problem lies in. Following is a working sample of module except for the function delete_multiple_server_confirm_form_submit which never gets executed.

```
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['testservers'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage Servers',
    'page callback' => 'display_servers_callback',
    'page arguments' => array('delete'),
    'access callback' => true,
  );

  return $items;
}


function display_servers_callback($args = '') {

  $op = isset($_POST['op']) ? $_POST['op'] : $args;
  $op = strtolower($op);
  $build_form = array();

  if (!empty($_POST['table']) && isset($_POST['operation']) && ($_POST['operation'] == 'delete')) {
    $options = $_POST['table'];
    $build_form['delete_multiple_server_confirm_form'] = drupal_get_form('delete_multiple_server_confirm_form', $options);
  }
  else {


    $build_form['display_servers_form'] = drupal_get_form('display_servers_form');
  }

  return $build_form;
}


function delete_multiple_server_confirm_form($form, &$form_state, $servers) {


  $path = current_path();

  return confirm_form($form, t('Are you sure you want to delete %title?'), $path, t('This action cannot be undone.'), t('Delete'), t('Cancel')
  );
}


function display_servers_form($form, $form_state) {


  $header = array(
    'server_name' => array('data' => t('Server Name')),
    'location' => array('data' => t('Location')),
    'protocols' => array('data' => t('Protocols')),
    'status' => array('data' => t('server status ')),
  );

  $servers = array(
    array('server_name' => 'us1', 'location' => 'us', 'protocols' => 'test', 'status' => 'ok'),
    array('server_name' => 'us2', 'location' => 'us', 'protocols' => 'test', 'status' => 'ok'),
    array('server_name' => 'us3', 'location' => 'us', 'protocols' => 'test', 'status' => 'ok'),
  );

  $options = array();



  for ($index = 0; $index < count($servers); $index++) {


    $options[$index] = array(
      'server_name' => $servers[$index]['server_name'],
      'location' => $servers[$index]['location'],
      'protocols' => $servers[$index]['protocols'],
      'status' => $servers[$index]['status'],
    );
  }


  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No servers found'),
  );



  $options = array();
  $operations = array('delete' => array(
      'label' => t('delete servers'),
      'callback' => 'delete_multiples',
    ),
    'suspend' => array(
      'label' => t('suspend servers'),
    ),
  );

  foreach ($operations as $operation => $array) {
    $options[$operation] = $array['label'];
  }




  $form['options']['operation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Operation'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => 'delete',
  );


  $form['options']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Update'),
  );


  return $form;
}


function delete_multiple_server_confirm_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $servers) {

  drupal_set_message('working');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After careful rereading of the user module, i realize that 2 more hidden form values need to be added so  the same delete_multiple_server_confirm_form will get called again after confirming action,otherwise the display_server_form will be rendered.

```
$form['table'] = array('#prefix' => '<ul>', '#suffix' => '</ul>', '#tree' => TRUE);
$form['operation'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => 'delete');

 foreach($servers as $id) {


    $form['table'][$id] = array(
         '#type' => 'hidden',
         '#value' => $id,
         );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$form['options']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Update'),
  '#submit' => array('delete_multiple_server_confirm_form_submit'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this makes no difference

Comment: This would work if you did it in a `form_alter` hook (and changed it to `$form['actions']['submit']`), but if you look at the code for [`confirm_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7) you can see it initialises `$form['actions']['submit']` explicitly, overwriting anything you might already have added in the original form function

Answer (score 0):

Change you function name from `delete_multiple_server_confirm_form_submit` to `display_servers_form_submit`

Comment: no, that will defeat its purpose, and i want it to have its own submit handler. the user module has a user_multiple_cancel_confirm and user_multiple_cancel_confirm_submit which work just like this

Answer (score -1):

If you are rendering your form using form--anyformname.tpl.php template file then make sure in that template file you are rendering these three thing at the end:

```
    <div>        
    <?php print render($form['form_id']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['form_build_id']);?>
    <?php print render($form['form_token']); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: The OP is NOT using any theme to render the form. The question is: Why isn't the form submission handler of my module invoked?